# Could not find generator nifty:scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying a simple RoR application and using `nifty generator` scripts for scaffolding, layout files, authentication.

I added to my gemfile `gem 'nifty-generators'` and i ran `'bundle install'` and it installed.

Then i entered

```
$ rails g nifty:scaffold Recipe name:string index new
```

I got the following exception

> Could not find generator nifty:scaffold

What could be the issue here

Comment: Perhaps double check the gem was installed where it should have been: $bundle show nifty-generators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3 ( of course you do since you are beginner), then use scaffold instead of nifty:scaffold

Like this

```
rails g scaffold
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much to dig in here.. Make sure that the `bundle install` or `bundle update` command has create an entry for `nifty-generators` in your `Gemfile.lock`.. Then verify that the gem has been installed correctly by using the `bundle show nifty-generators` .. It should show the location of the gem on your system.. Make sure that you at least have read permissions to that folder..

Answer (score 0):

Since you added the gem with bundler/your gemfile I imagine you would want to do:

```
$ bundle exec rails g nifty:scaffold Recipe name:string index new
```

for the gem to be found.